# pandas: T/F for if two ranges intersect

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have two dataframes that might look like this:

df1:

```
name    start    end
stuart  0        20
lamp    32       34
hamlet  16       100
```

df2:

```
name    start    end
LOXL1   30       40
FOXP3   0        11
INSN    43       70
```

I've seen many answers that find the intersection between two ranges. My favorite is:

```
range(max(start_1, start_2), min(end_1, end_2))
```

That's fine. But, for my context, I just need to know if the two ranges intersect at all. I can't seem to find an answer that works for my use case. Expected output would basically grab the names from df2 for which the range intersected with df1. Expected output would be:

```
name    start    end    intersects
stuart  0        20     FOXP3
lamp    32       34     LOXL1
hamlet  16       100    LOXL1|INSN
```

Or, if this is easier (this solution would actually be ideal, but I can work with the first one):

```
name    start    end    intersects
stuart  0        20     FOXP3
lamp    32       34     LOXL1
hamlet  16       100    LOXL1
hamlet  16       100    INSN
```

What I'm effectively stuck on is getting a True/False out of whether ranges between two rows intersect, without a for loop. A for loop is not a viable solution for me because I have 40k rows being compared to 6m rows.

Comment: Are `start` and `end` always integers? Do you expect the intercepts to be sparse? If so, there may be an algorithmic speedup relative to the naive approach.

Comment: Start and End are always integers, but I'm unsure about the sparsity of the intercepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using the mathmetical way + `numpy` `broadcast`

```
v1=df1.start.values
v2=df1.end.values
s1=df2.start.values
s2=df2.end.values
s=pd.DataFrame(((s2-v1[:,None])>0)&((s1-v2[:,None])<0)).dot(df2.name+'|').str[:-1]
s
Out[737]: 
0         FOXP3
1         LOXL1
2    LOXL1|INSN
dtype: object

#df1['New']=s.values
```

Comment: This worked really well, but I do have a problem: 

My df2 is 1254113 rows long. For my test case of df1 with 200 rows, this still worked well. My actual df1 has 40,000 rows (potentially larger in the future). Running this with a df1 of 60,000 hit a `MemoryError`. 

Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: @JohnRouhana you may consider split the df1  into chunk

Comment: That seems to be my only option if I'm to use this method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question you need to answer, from what you already have, is whether there is anything in the `range` you know.

```
if max(start_1, start_2) <= min(end_1, end_2):
```

You might find better tools in the `interval` module; this does a variety of operations on known intervals; I'm hopeful there are vectorized tools you can use.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain that I understand your response, but I'll check out the interval module. Thanks for suggesting.